# passing value of array to the start of the loop

Tags: c, arrays

My goal is to have the user view the history of entered commands (`historyArray` - done) and allow him to re-run any command in history, by entering `history 1`, `history 2` where `1` and `2` is the number of the list of commands as printed-out from `historyArray`.
I have managed to  obtain the index from the second parameter (`history 1`) of the user input. My question is now, how to execute that specific command obtained from `history N`?

So, for example:

```
     hshell> test [Enter]
     Command not found
     hshell> history 1
     Command not found
```

Here is my progress:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=0; int j=0; int k=0;
    int elementCounter = 0;
    char inputString[100];
    char *result=NULL;
    char delims[] = " ";
    char historyArray[30][20] = {0};
    char tokenArray[20][20] ;
    int tempIndex = 0;
    char hCommand[2][20]={0};

    do
    {
             j = 0;
             printf("hshell>");
             gets(inputString);

             strcpy (historyArray[k], inputString);
             k = (k+1) % 20;

            if (elementCounter <= 20)
             {         
              elementCounter++;                
             }

             if (elementCounter == 21)
             {
                k = 20;
                for (i=0; i<20; i++)
                {
                    strcpy(historyArray[i], historyArray[i+1]);
                }
                 strcpy (historyArray[19], inputString);                 
             }

             // Break the string into parts
             result = strtok(inputString, delims);


             while (result!=NULL)
             {
                  strcpy(tokenArray[j], result);
                   j++;
                  result= strtok(NULL, delims);                      
             }

              if (strcmp(tokenArray[0], "exit") == 0)
              {
                 return 0;
              }
              else if (strcmp(tokenArray[0], "history") ==  0)
              {
                   if (j>1)
                   { 
                      tempIndex = atoi(tokenArray[1]);
                     strcpy(hCommand,historyArray[tempIndex-1]);
                     puts(hCommand);
                    // tempIndex = atoi(tokenArray[j]);
                     //puts(tempIndex);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //print history array
                       for (i=0; i<elementCounter-1;i++)
                           printf("%i. %s\n", i+1, historyArray[i]);
                   }
              }
              else
              {
                  printf("Command not found\n");
              }



    }while (1);
}
```

- `hCommand` is where I store the command as obtained from `historyArray`.
- I am using a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'system' function in stdlib.h.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

This function is included in both windows and *nix. You do not need to worry about calling `fork` or `CreateProcess` separately, this will take care of it for you. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

In your code, you would write:

```
system(hCommand);
```

It will return when the command finishes (it is a synchronous call).

Comment: How can i modify it so it can work with custom commands? For future program editing I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The `system` command will execute whatever you pass to it, as if you had typed it on the command line.

Comment: Do you mean more custom commands like the 'exit' case that you have in your code?

Comment: @voth1234 That's a design decision you're going to have to make on your own. It looks like you're writing a shell. Internal custom commands like `exit` in your code obviously aren't callable with `system`. If I were you, I'd make each internal command a function, then store a pointer to that function in a lookup structure like a trie or hashmap. When the user types a command, look it up and call the function, or if it isn't found, pass the command through to `system`.

Comment: @voth1234 ...or if you don't have too many custom commands, just make a chain of if/else statements like you currently have with 'exit' and 'history'. Don't overcomplicate it if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the name of the command you wanna execute I would suggest going through the system call [**exec**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). Take into account the **exec** replaces the current process image with the one you are going to execute. Otherwise you might be interested in [**fork**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork).

**EDIT#1** Then I believe you need [**this API**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that I am not familiar which of those functions are equivalent to the ones I have provided in first place. With a bit time you could figure it out, right? :)

Comment: @voth1234 Check mine edited answer. **CreateProcess** might be suitable for you needs at first glance.

Comment: They say that two heads are better than one :)

Comment: @voth1234 Yes, then the stated function would fit because creates new process in the context of the caller.